# Hiding a container, updating the innerHTML and then showing it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to hide a container, update the innerHTML of the container and then show the container again. I know that both actions are possible however when combined together - innerHTML does not seem to update...

Here's the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/definaly/k4xuscz1/58/

Is this possible?

(Additional question for discussion - Do you think this is a suitable asynchronous way to switch between the pages of the website? Is there anything that can go wrong with this method?)

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    var content = $('.content');
    
    content.hide('slide', {direction:'left'} ,400);
    
    content.innerHTML = "<h3>Page One</h3>";

    content.show('slide', {direction:'right'} ,400);
    
});
```

```css
.content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="button"> Click me </button>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Also this is my first time using JSfiddle so please let me know if the link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `innerHTML` you just use `html` with jQuery. Also, instead of using a fragile `setTimeout` that will break if you change the duration in your `hide` but forget to change it in the `setTimeout`, you can just use the fourth parameter of the `hide` method. It takes a function that will run when the hiding animation completes.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
    var content = $('.content');
    
    
    content.hide('slide', {direction:'left'} ,400, function() {
        content.html("<h3>Page One</h3>");    
    });

    content.show('slide', {direction:'right'});
    
});
```

```css
.content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="button"> Click me </button>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you very much.- never knew that the hide function had an additional argument.

Answer (score 1):

Prefacing this with: I am not 100% sure if this is the ideal way to do it, but you can get the desired results with the following JS.

Change your JS to:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var content = $('.content');

    content.hide('slide', {direction:'left'} ,400);
    setTimeout(function(){
        content.html("<h3>Page One</h3>");
    }, 400)

    content.show('slide', {direction:'right'} ,400);

});
```

This will set a rudimentary sleep to prevent the changes from showing up while the div is sliding off screen, and use the .html() function that jquery offers for consistency.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)

Comment: @MaxwellS that will work but it's a little bit fragile. See my answer for an alternative. Not meant to knock your answer, just trying to help everyone learn about other alternatives.

Comment: @ToddChaffee Thanks! Didn't know that you could pass a fourth argument -- I really appreciate the feedback, it's awesome to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery. The jQuery Syntax to change the inner html is not `.innerHtml = "<blah>"`

it is `.html("<blah>")`

So change `content.innerHTML = "<h3>Page One</h3>";` to `content.html("<h3>Page One</h3>");`